# git aws.push removes dynamically created files from server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Git repository and `eb` (Elastic Beanstalk) command line tool to deploy the code to server (Ruby on Rails application).

I am using following steps to commit the updates and push it to the server

1. `git commit -a`
2. `git push`
3. `git aws.push`

My application has folders/files which is created at run time, and which holds in the public folder, but on each deploy on server will erase the files that is created on run time.

I think that the folder (`/var/app/current`) in server is replacing with the latest Git project code.

I need to retain the files in each deploy, please help.

Answer (score 2):

Correct. A new deployment *replaces* the previous deployment. This is entirely by design.

One of the core tenets of *Cloud Computing* is that hardware is *disposable*, you instead want to store files that you want to hang onto in a persistent location (i.e., *not* the web server).

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can write your data to S3, DynamoDB, or another off-server location.